# ProcessCmdKey does not pass Enter Key

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, keystroke

Something has happened that is causing my code to *always* capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key but never process it.  Meaning *all* my data entry boxes, grid controls etc. are broken.  It is like the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key has been switched off.

I have tried removing the `ProcessCmdKey` routine completely and it is still doing it.

I had a rather lengthy piece of code that processes the <kbd>enter</kbd> key on a tabbed form, but it was messing up the other tabs, meaning that whenever <kbd>enter</kbd> was pressed it would capture it.

So, I just checked to see what tab it was on and ignore it if not the correct tab, simple?  no.

For whatever reason no matter *what* I do my form will NOT process the enter key.

I have gone back to the most basic of code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

From what I understand the above should really do nothing, just pass the key pressed back and then process it.

And that works for everything except the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.  If I have a textbox or any control then it will take all input, but it just completely ignores the <kbd>enter</kbd>key.  I have tried `return false;` as well and that does not work.

I have even tried completely *removing* the routine and it is *still* broken.  restarted VS just in case.

EDIT:
OK, here is the complete original code before I started to "fix" things.  This works correctly, except it stops the Enter key from working *anywhere* else in the program.  Which as you can imagine is not greatly appreciated by the end users.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if (ActiveControl.Name.ToString() != "order_creation_grid") //ensures that we don't caputre keypresses in the datagrid
        {

            //if (keyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift)) //tabbing backwards
            //{
            //    if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_con_name_DD")
            //    {
            //        order_con_name_DD.Select();
            //        order_con_name_DD.ShowDropDown();

            //    }
            //}
            if (keyData == Keys.Tab || keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_shipper_dd")
                {
                    var test = keyData;
                    //getAllConsignees(); remove
                    get_all_addresses(); //load up the address dd
                    order_address_dd.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    order_address_dd.Select();
                    order_address_dd.Focus();
                    return true;//lets the system know that the control key was handled and not to fire it again
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_address_dd")
                {
                    if (order_address_dd.SelectedIndex != -1)//only do this if there is not a new address in the address chooser ie: found one in database
                    {
                    order_match_dd.Select();
                    order_match_dd.Focus();
                        order_match_dd.ShowDropDown();
                    return true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        order_address_eb.Value = order_address_dd.Text;
                        order_consignee_eb.Select();
                        order_consignee_eb.Focus();
                        return true; ;
                    }
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Name.ToString() == "order_match_dd")
                {
                    if (order_match_dd.SelectedIndex != -1)//fire off when a valid selection is made
                    {
                        //check if it is a new item

                        if (order_match_dd.Text == "1 New")
                        {
                            //blank out the fields and position cursor to Consignee
                            clear_order_fields();

                            order_consignee_eb.Select();
                            order_consignee_eb.Focus();
                        }
                        else //parse the value in the match box useing the seperator | into strings and load up the correct fields
                        {
                            char[] delimiterChars = { '|' };
                            string[] fields = order_match_dd.Text.Split(delimiterChars);

                            clear_order_fields();

                            order_consignee_eb.Value = fields[0].ToString().Trim(); ;
                            order_address_eb.Value = fields[1].ToString().Trim();
                            order_city_eb.Value = fields[2].ToString().Trim();
                            order_state_eb.Value = fields[3].ToString().Trim();
                            order_zip_eb.Value = fields[4].ToString().Trim();
                            //go try and match the driver and facility with this zipcode
                            get_driver_facility();

                            order_BOL_eb.Select();
                            order_BOL_eb.Focus();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_BOL_eb")
                {
                    int custID = Convert.ToInt16(order_shipper_dd.SelectedValue);

                    string testFor = order_BOL_eb.Value.ToString();

                    var lookFor = (from l in dbContext.stop_details
                                   where l.cust_unique_id == testFor && l.customer_id == custID
                                   select l).ToArray();

                    int count = lookFor.Count();
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                       MessageBox.Show("WARNING..this BOL has been used before for this customer, make sure you really want to use it again.");
                    }
                    order_loose_qty.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_consignee_eb")
                {

                    order_address_eb.Select();
                    order_address_eb.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_address_eb")
                {

                    order_city_eb.Select();
                    order_city_eb.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_city_eb")
                {

                    order_state_eb.Select();
                    order_state_eb.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_state_eb")
                {

                    order_zip_eb.Select();
                    order_zip_eb.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_zip_eb")
                {
                  //  get_driver_facility();

                    order_BOL_eb.Select();
                    order_BOL_eb.Focus();
                    return true;
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_note")
                {
                   //auto send to the grid if checkboxed

                    if (autoSend_cb.Checked)
                    {
                        send_to_orderGrid();

                    }
                    //otherwise just sit there...
                    return true;
                }
            }


            if (keyData == Keys.Enter) //On enter key for these controls fire the tab key so that it will move to the next control
            {

                if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_loose_weight")
                {
                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_loose_qty")
                {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_pallets_qty")
                {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_pallets_weight")
                {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_hazmat_weight")
                {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

                }
                else if (ActiveControl.Parent.Name.ToString() == "order_COD")
                {

                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");

                }

            }
            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.OemCloseBrackets))
            {
                this.order_shipper_dd.Select();
                this.order_shipper_dd.ShowDropDown();
                return true;
            }

            if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Enter)) //when ctrl-enter is pressed in the Order Entry screen
            {
                send_to_orderGrid();


                return true;
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

I can even comment out the *entire* routine and it still does it.

Comment: you have a `return` on your first line!

Comment: The code returns on the first line, all code below is unreachable.

Comment: Yes...I know.  ignore the rest of it.  It still locks out my return key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure as to what you need. You have not defined what "process" the enter key means. My best guess:

1- Do you want the enter key to perform a new line in your text boxes? Change the AcceptsReturn property from False to True, and your text box should allow you to use the enter key to create a new line.

2 - Use the enter key to tab to the next control? Add a keyDown event to a text box and do something like this:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Enter:
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry...no, I really just want the Enter key to go back to working.  When the user presses "enter" it competley ignores it.  It is captureing it, but never returns it.  If I set a breakpoint, it does fire.  All other keys are passed back, meaning the tab key works, arrow keys work, anything they type works.  But when they press enter it is captured and then "thrown away" for lack of a better term.  It is like I am using a return true; but I am not.

Comment: @JoeRuder okay. If you can post more code I'll see if I can help further.

Comment: I uploaded the full routine, I am seriously at a loss.  I am going to try and see if I have something else captureing keys, but when the program is in debug mode it is not showing anything like that...

Comment: So basically you want this function to handle the _enter_ key based different conditions, but doing so only allows the enter key to be used for the outlined scenarios and nothing else? If you place a breakpoint at the top of this routine and step through to the end, does it reach "return base.ProcessCmdKey"?

Comment: yes.  and yes.  It reaches the last command correctly.  If I put the last command first (meaning the routine should just exit back out) it still blocks the Enter key from doing anything.

Comment: Is the control in question a Telerik WPF control?

Comment: No, it is a winforms.

Comment: @JoeRuder okay. What is the intended behavior for pressing the _enter_ key for controls that do not meet any of the conditions you defined here?

Comment: I just want it to pass the enter key on through.  And that is where it breaks.  It is captureing the enter key but never "resending" it.  I thought that was what return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);" was supposed to do.  I have verified that when in a break state keyData does in fact contain "Enter"

Comment: It depends on the control, but afaik controls such as Textbox, ComboBox, CheckBox etc. do not utilize the Enter key unless told to do so. If a control that is not explicitly used in your ProcessCmdKey function has the enter key pressed and nothing happens, it may be working as intended.

Comment: True, but these controls used to work (like yesterday).  Good idea however.

Comment: I am at another client location now, I will have to dig back into this in about 6 hours.  Thanks for the thoughts and help.  I have a couple ideas to try but need some focus time to do them.

Comment: I went through all the code, could not find anything wrong.  Finally went back to a older snapshot and then did a cut/paste of the new code.  For whatever reason it is working correct again.  I appreciate your time while I worked through this...

Answer (score 0):

Until you discover your real issue with the enter key consider doing this:

```
private void Form1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        e.IsInputKey = true;
}
```

Fairly obvious as to what it does but it should fix your situation for now. Does that help?

Comment: good idea...let me try that, I am waiting for a remote reboot to complete.  I tried something like that using sendKey to no effect.  I have never seen anything quite like this.

Comment: @JoeRuder Yeah seems really strange.. not sure exactly what else I can help you with without seeing the code. You're 100% sure there's no accidental overwrite of the function? Can you pinpoint exactly when in your project this first occurred? After which change?

Comment: not really...it was not until the customer called me a bit ago panicking because they cannot enter data.  I was making one of the data entry screens use the enter key instead of the tab key for them and *that* is working perfectly.  It just broke all of the other screens.  It is using a telerik   Tabbed control (meaning file folder like tabs, not the TAB key).  I will post the entire routine that broke everything up there just in case.